# Rails has_many through: (many to many relationship) error uninitialized constant Group::Keywords

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, has-many-through

A `Group` can have many keywords and a `Keyword` can have many groups. I have this relationship defined as

```
class Keyword < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :groups_keywords
   has_many :groups, through: :groups_keywords
end

class GroupsKeyword < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :groups
  belongs_to :keywords
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :groups_keywords
  has_many :keywords, through: :groups_keywords
end
```

I can do `Group.find(1).groups_keywords` so the relationship is working?

But I want to get all of my `Groups` keywords so I do the following.

`Group.find(1).keywords`

But I get the error `uninitialized constant Group::Keywords`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the below

```
class GroupsKeyword < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :groups
  belongs_to :keywords
end
```

to

```
class GroupsKeyword < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :keyword
end
```